# What's the best Rails convention for this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-attributes, virtual-attribute

Let's say that you have a resource that is created and displayed entirely within the view of another resource (eg. comments or tags). Should you still make it it's own resource, or would it be a better idea to make it a nested resource? Also, should you make use of virtual attributes?

I know this question is general, but I'm not looking for a specific answer, just a general explanation of when each technique is preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some general thoughts:

- Nesting and independent resources are not necessarily mutually exclusive.
- "created and displayed entirely within the view of another resource" is a strong statement that can end up not being true.  For example, tags: do you ever want a list of all articles with a certain tag.  that would not make sense nested.
- Nesting below the second or third level will begin to be more trouble then its worth. Some will say that even the first nesting is more trouble then its worth.
- For an app that has a single dominate resource the cost of adding other independent resources is proportionally higher.  Small apps can get away with complexities that large apps cannot.
- If you don't have a good feel yet write a few resources each way. Answers will at best be justifies opinions it is probably best to develop you own through experience.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, it would be more useful to make it a nested resource. This is the more "RESTful" way. It will also give you access to the parent resource without having to specify it as a parameter. However, you do not want to nest a resource more than one level deep, as noted in the [Rails routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).